# Asp.net core 5 Items List

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, listview, asp.net-core-5.0, html-datalist

I am new to asp.net and I have created an attendance system where I can a list of employees from the DB and when I click a button "In" it save a timestamp for when that employee came in.

So far, I have a normal table list of employees with the buttons in a separate column and I would like to change the design to look somewhat like the one in the attached image.
However, I do not know the what to use to be able to create that. [Employee List ItemList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58ClT.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

search in youtube how to make horizontal card in css
or this should be help u
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QB9agsk42Q

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.